# UWP access controls in ListViewItem from colletion

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

I have a ListView with two DataTemplate for items and headers.
Items from the ListView are binded to CollectionViewSource which looks like this:

```
<CollectionViewSource
            x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource3"
            Source="{Binding Groups2}"
            IsSourceGrouped="true"
            ItemsPath="Items"
            d:Source="{Binding Groups, Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:SampleDataSource}}"/>
```

I can manage to get ListViewItem but I cant get control of its child controls.
My ListView looks like this:

```
<ListView
                                            Margin="0,40,0,0"
                                            Width="580"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                            x:Name="itemGridView1"
                                            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                                            AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource2}}"
                                            SelectionMode="None"
                                            IsSwipeEnabled="false"
                                            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                                            ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick" Background="White">
                                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="LightGray" Width="2500" Height="25">
                                                        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="50" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LiveTime}" Foreground="{Binding LiveTimeBGColor}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="40" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TeamOne}" Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Right" Width="150" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                                                                    <Border Background="DarkGray" Width="35" Margin="0,0,2,0" Padding="15,0,0,0">
                                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ScoreTeamOne}"  Width="30" Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                                                                    </Border>
                                                                    <Border Background="DarkGray" Width="35" Padding="15,0,0,0" Margin="2,0,0,0">
                                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ScoreTeamTwo}" Foreground="White" Width="30" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                                                                    </Border>
                                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TeamTwo}" Margin="10,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" /> 
                                                                </StackPanel>
                                                            </StackPanel>
                                                        </Border>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                                            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                                                <GroupStyle>
                                                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,2" Width="2500" Background="{Binding HeaderLiveBGColor}">
                                                                <Button Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                                                AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                                                Click="Header_Click"
                                                                Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}" Width="2500">
                                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="2500">
                                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LeagueTitle}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="441.9" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                                </Button>
                                                            </Grid>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                                </GroupStyle>
                                            </ListView.GroupStyle>
                                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                    <ItemsWrapGrid GroupPadding="0,0,20,0" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                        </ListView>
```

Any idea how can I check if the rights child control was clicked?
What I want to eventually achieve is the handle a click based on the controls of the ListViewItem clicked.

Comment: Why did you want to get the child controls in ListViewItem?

Comment: To get the clicked item from ListViewItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To get the clicked item from ListViewItem

If you add break points to debug your code, you could know there's a `ClickedItem` in `ItemClickEventArgs` class object. The `ClickedItem` should be that you want.

Another way is using **TwoWay** Binding on the SelectedItem.

Both the two ways are included in the following code sample:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource3"
        Source="{Binding Groups2}"
        IsSourceGrouped="true"
        ItemsPath="Items" />
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView
                                        Margin="0,40,0,0"
                                        Width="580"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                        x:Name="itemGridView1"
                                        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                                        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource3}}"
                                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSong,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                        SelectionMode="Single"
                                        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
                                        IsItemClickEnabled="True"

                                        ItemClick="ItemGridView_ItemClick" Background="White">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="LightGray" Width="2500" Height="25">
                    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="50" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,2" Width="2500" Background="{Binding HeaderLiveBGColor}">
                            <Button Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                                            AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"

                                                            Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}" Width="2500">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="2500">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="441.9" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid GroupPadding="0,0,20,0" Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<SongGroup> Groups2 { get; set; }

    private Song _SelectedSong;

    public Song SelectedSong
    {
        get { return _SelectedSong; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedSong = value;
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Groups2 = GenerateData();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<SongGroup> GenerateData()
    {
        ObservableCollection<SongGroup> songGroups = new ObservableCollection<SongGroup>();

        ObservableCollection<Song> songs = new ObservableCollection<Song>();
        songs.Add(new Song() { Title = "Song1" });
        songs.Add(new Song() { Title = "Song2" });

        songGroups.Add(new SongGroup() { Key = "A", Items = songs });

        ObservableCollection<Song> songs2 = new ObservableCollection<Song>();
        songs2.Add(new Song() { Title = "Song2_1" });
        songs2.Add(new Song() { Title = "Song2_2" });
        songGroups.Add(new SongGroup() { Key = "B", Items = songs2 });

        return songGroups;
    }

    private void ItemGridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var song = e.ClickedItem;
    }
}

public class Song
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class SongGroup
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Song> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: e.ClickedItem will return the ListViewItem not the child control clicked in the ListViewItem.
If you try to convert it to TextBlock for example, Null exception is thrown no matter what

Comment: I think you didn't really understand what I am looking for. I want to get control of the child controls of my ListViewItem

Comment: @GeorgeH. What did you want to do with the textblock? To get its text value?

Comment: @GeorgeH. In order to get the property value of a control in the DataTemplate, most developers will try to find the control previously. But this is not a good practice. Using **TwoWay** binding to bind the SelectedItem would be better.

Comment: TwoWay banding i think is not possible here as I can not bind selecteditem due to having different types of groups to bind to the listview.
But you gave me the solution. I just had to cast the e.ClickedItem to my ObservableCollection and then ask for infos. Cheers